# Getting the right most in regex

Tags: regex

I am wanting to split the following text in groups:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1111.........................................................................US$ 124,85   
1111........AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA....................................US$ 124,85
11111.......CCC.CCC..........................................................US$ 140,07
11111.......DDDDDDDDDD.......................................................US$ 157,33
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am using this pattern ([fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/70Gviv/1))

```
/(\d{4,6})(\.\.+)(.+)(\.\.+)(US\$\s)(\d+)\,(\d{2})/g
```

It is almost doing what I want, but the name of product (group 3) is with dots at the end (the dots should be in the group 4). I know that Regex has the left most longest rule, but even trying a lot of things I was not able to achieve it.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that the name could be an empty string, what drove my decision of using (\.\.+) instead of (\.+) - to get a single dot as name. Sorry about that.

Comment: You want read the product name until you encounter a dot. So [^.]+ is best for group 3. Correction: your productname can possibly have a '.'. Let me answer that in a proper answer.

Comment: `[^.]+` for group 3 will not correctly capture line 2's product name: `CCC.CCC`

Comment: Updated my answer for an empty product name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your regex so the last match in the product name is not a period - `[^.]`. This will have the capture end at the last non-period character while still capturing periods in the middle of the product name such as your `CCC.CCC` example product name.

To get a single `.` as a product name when none is present as you mention, you can use an or to capture a single dot or multiple characters as `(.|.+[^.])`:

`/(\d{4,6})(\.+)(.|.+[^.])(\.+)(US\$\s)(\d+)\,(\d{2})/g`

https://regex101.com/r/qnn5N8/3

You can also capture an empty string for the product name when it is empty by using `(|.+[^.])` as mentioned by @mlambrichs in the comments below:

`/(\d{4,6})(\.+)(|.+[^.])(\.+)(US\$\s)(\d+)\,(\d{2})/g`

https://regex101.com/r/qnn5N8/4

This example also cleans up the regex a bit by removing the extra period `\.\.+` on both sides of the product name like below. This works because the first match is greedy and will match everything that is a period while the second match is surrounded by non period characters.

Comment: Your answer is very fine. I just forgot to include the case of name being empty. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries. Empty product name case has been added above and in the updated regex101 link.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. I just can´t think regex way yet.

Comment: I used to use O'Reilly's Mastering Regular Expressions book a lot. It's a great book and one of the few that I actually went back to over and over again.

Comment: @Grokify. Agreed on your book statement. On your regex: why not change the product to (|.*[^.])? Then your productname can be really empty. In your regex it still can be '.'.

Comment: A dot was used to represent an empty product name because @Nizam indicated that's what he was looking for: "drove my decision [...] to get a single dot as name"

Comment: @Grokify No, he said that's the way he solved it. We should explain him that that's not the way to go.

Comment: I've updated the answer to cover the option of capturing an empty string for the product name and credited you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DYcxls/5)

The regex

```
(?<nr>\d{4,6})(?:\.+)(?<product>(.*[^.]|))(?:\.+)US\$\s(?<dollars>\d+),(?<cents>\d{2})
```

shows that productname can contain a '.'. somewhere in the name.

Comment: Ok. Question updated: productname can be empty. Going to adapt my answer.

Comment: I just forgot to include the case of name being empty. Sorry about that.

Comment: Adjusted. ([A-Z]+\.?[A-Z]+|) is more accurate, because it matches a productname with possibly a '.' somewhere in the middle OR productname is empty.

Comment: Fails if the product name is "Power saw 5000" or "V8 vegetable juice"

Comment: @RobertMcKee Fair enough. Let's make the productname something like (|.*[^.]). Like https://regex101.com/r/DYcxls/4

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing what you ask, this is what I would have used:

```
(\d{4,6})\.{2,}([^.]+(?:\.[^.]+)*)?\.{2,}US\$\s(\d+\,\d{2})
```

This will have 3 captures per line: product id, product description, and price.

Comment: I am kinf of embarrassed, but I forgot to include a very important example of problem I could have. Sorry about that.

Comment: Then just add a `?` after the product name capturing group.